# Cypher: Label Syntax - use "OR" while constraining nodes with labels?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Cypher newb here who probably can't get my head out of "thinking in SQL":

Let's say I have a graph of Star Wars characters and their kids (and their kids, and so on).

I have a relationship in place between a parent and child. If *I want to return nodes of all of the progeny of Anakin Skywalker (including him, too)*, I might do this:

```
MATCH  (x:Person {name:"Darth Vader"})-[:CHILD_OF*1..3]-(y) 
RETURN x,y
```

What if I want to compare the progeny of two characters, though? Let's say I want to see the spawn of both Anakin and the loathsome Jar Jar Binks. Is there any way to essentially OR the label constraint?

```
MATCH  (x:Person {name:"Darth Vader | "Jar Jar"})-[:CHILD_OF*1..3]-(y) 
RETURN x,y
```

No.

```
MATCH  (x:Person {name:("Darth Vader", "Jar Jar")})-[:CHILD_OF*1..3]-(y) 
RETURN x,y
```

Fail.

```
MATCH  (x:Person {name:"Darth Vader"} OR {name: "Jar Jar"})-[:CHILD_OF*1..3]-(y) 
RETURN x,y
```

Sadness.

Or MUST I use a WHERE clause (which would break [:CHILD_OF*1..3], right? I'd assume the WHERE gets applied before [:CHILD_OF1..3] gets evaluated?)

Thanks much.

Comment: Do you mean labels or properties? `name` in your example is a property, `:Person` is a label.

Comment: Property. Thanks for pointing this out - still getting my head around the vocabulary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to use a `WHERE` clause.  And it shouldn't break the variable length path:

```
MATCH  (x:Person)-[:CHILD_OF*1..3]-(y) 
WHERE x.name IN ['Darth Vader', 'Jar Jar']
RETURN x, y
```

Neo4j is smart enough to know you're saying "start with `x` which matches these criteria and then form the path from there".  The JSON match syntax is syntactic sugar for a simple `WHERE` equality match and can only be used for strict equality.

If you wanted to know how disconnected `x` and `y` are or see the nodes/relationships in between you can define a path variable:

```
MATCH  path=(x:Person)-[:CHILD_OF*1..3]-(y) 
WHERE x.name IN ['Darth Vader', 'Jar Jar']
RETURN x, path, nodes(path), rels(path), y
```

**EDIT:**

If it helps, another way to do it / think about it is to use a `WITH` clause:

```
MATCH (x:Person)
WHERE x.name IN ['Darth Vader', 'Jar Jar'])
WITH x
MATCH  (x)-[:CHILD_OF*1..3]-(y) 
RETURN x,y
```